# How to resolve 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, I am new to coding.

I am trying to simulate source flow in Python. But I am getting an error. How can I resolve it? Here's my code and error:

**Code**

```
import numpy as nm
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sympy import *
import math as math
X,Y=symbols('X Y')
N=50
x_start,x_end=-2,2
y_start,y_end=-1,1
x=nm.linspace(x_start,x_end,N)
y=nm.linspace(y_start,y_end,N)
X,Y=nm.meshgrid(x,y)
width=10.0
height=width*((y_end-y_start)/(x_end-x_start))
pyplot.figure(figsize=(width,height))
pyplot.xlabel("X")
pyplot.ylabel("Y")
strength_source=10
x_source,y_source=-0.5,-0.25
q=(Y - y_source)/(X - x_source)
u_source = (strength_source / (2 * math.pi) * diff(atan(q),Y))
v_source = (strength_source / (2 * math.pi) * diff(atan(q),X))
pyplot.scatter(x_source,y_source)
pyplot.streamplot(X,Y,u_source,v_source,density=1, linewidth=1,
arrowsize=2, arrowstyle='->')
```

**Error:**

```
  File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sympy\functions\elementary\trigonometric.py", line 2298, in eval
    if arg.could_extract_minus_sign():

AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'
```

Comment: You should include the full traceback.  Right now, we have no idea which line of your code is throwing the error/exception.  All we know is that line 2298 of sympy\functions\elementary\trigonometric.py doesn't like what you're giving it.

Comment: That said, there's an open issue in sympy that may have clues to your issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5721

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the function parameter 'atan'. This function takes only one argument x and returns the arc tangent of x. Your code is passing a vector to the function. Try to create a list of points with the calculated tangent arc. Something like that:

```
array_resul_atan = []
for i in range(len(q)):
    atan_q = []
    for j in range(len(q[i])):
        atan_q.append(atan(q[i][j]))
    array_resul_atan.append(atan_q)

array_resul_atan = np.asarray(array_resul_atan, dtype='float')
```

Similarly, the diff function takes only one array as a parameter. Your code is passing two arrays. My suggestion is to review the formula and look for a better way to differentiate.

Hope this helps.