# 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'

Tags: python, sympy

Hello I am trying to run this code but this error message appears : 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'

Please help, I've never used sympy before

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

L = 1
m = 1
g = 9.81

k = 2
a = sp.solve(2.5*L*m*g*(sp.sin(phi)) + m*g*(sp.cos(phi))*(0.5*L+(L/(sp.tan(phi)))), phi) 
print(a)
```

After some modifications, it is working :

```
import sympy as sp

L = 1
m = 1
g = 9.81
k = 2


phi = sp.Symbol('phi')
x = sp.Symbol('x')

expr1 = 2.5*L*m*g*(sp.sin(phi)) + m*g*(sp.cos(phi))*(0.5*L+x)
expr2 = m*g*sp.sin(phi) + k*x
b = sp.solve([sp.simplify(expr1), sp.simplify(expr2)] , [phi , x])
print(b)  #une expression réelle
```

Comment: I guess you need to define "phi"

Comment: Omit the `math` and `numpy` imports when using `sympy` (unless you know what you are doing with them).  You may need to read more of the `sympy` tutorials.

Comment: but why do i need to define phi? In my "solve" i'm looking for the values that phi could take to solve my equation

Comment: You don't have to give `phi` a numeric value, but you still have to define it as a `sympy.symbol`.  Step back and do some more basic `sympy` reading.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  But when I do a web search, I found an earlier SO question, [How to resolve 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611084/how-to-resolve-immutabledensendimarray-object-has-no-attribute-could-extract).  A big problem is that you did not provide the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you've described doesn't really match up with the code you've given, so it's likely you had some variables defined differently.

The code you gave doesn't run because you don't have `phi` defined. You need to do

```
phi = Symbol('phi')
```

You will also need to simplify your expression to make solve work on it. Note that it only has complex solutions

```
>>> phi = Symbol('phi')
>>> expr = 2.5*L*m*g*(sp.sin(phi)) + m*g*(sp.cos(phi))*(0.5*L+(L/(sp.tan(phi))))
>>> solve(simplify(expr), phi)
[-0.160875277198321 - 0.71616371255285*I, -0.160875277198321 + 0.71616371255285*I, 2.98071737639147 - 0.71616371255285*I, 2.98071737639147 + 0.71616371255285*I]
```

As far as I can tell it doesn't have a real solution. A [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9.81*%280.5+%2B+1%2Ftan%28phi%29%29*cos%28phi%29+%2B+24.525*sin%28phi%29&dataset=) at Wolfram Alpha seems to confirm this. If you are expecting a real solution you should double check your expression.

Comment: Yes thank you @asmeurer , I am supposed to find a real solution between this equation and another (m*g*sin(phi) + k*x = 0 where phi and x are unknowed). My expressions should be correct. The solution must respect a condition (tan(phi) = L/x). And after that I have to find the better value for k. I'm still searching for how to do that.

Comment: It is now working, I changed some part of the expression